# How to use keras InceptionV3 model in tensorflow 1.11?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In tensorflow 1.10,I could call function tensorflow.keras.applications.InceptionV3() to create a InceptionV3 model.

However, the keras.applications module seems to be removed in Tensorflow 1.11.

According to the API r1.11 reference, keras Applications are canned architectures with pre-trained weights.

Should I download the model file and load it?

Nevertheless, where could I get it from?

Comment: You could just use keras from pip, not the version bundled with tensorflow, as the keras.applications module was moved in its own repository and no idea where it is now inside tensorflow

Comment: I have to use the tensorflow keras,because the the model would be warped in a    estimator in order to be trained on the clusters.